# Android: Not finding File.toPath option with JDK. 1.70.51

Tags: android, java-7

I just upgraded to java 1.70.51 from a 1.6 version.

Its my first time changing the jdk. I've successfully compiled and ran my Android program using some of the new features, like Files.copy(), but I can't seem to find File.toPath?

```
 File src_db = get_dbfolder(src_dbName, src_location);
 File dst_db = get_dbfolder(dst_dbName, dst_location);

 Path srcPath = src_db.toPath();  // these are giving me errors,
 Path destPath = dst_db.toPath(); // because no .toPath
```

I looked through the settings, and I do see 1.6 settings for the compiler, but if I change it to 1.7 I get android requires 5.0 or 6.0 compiler settings (i guess that means 1.5 or 1.6).   Am I allowed to use 1.7 with android?  Is that the cause of this problem?

The workspace jre is set to 1.7, but compiler settings are 1.6, which i can't change without error.

Comment: You are declaring "File src_db" but later you use "src.toPath()". Must be src_db.toPath, dont you think?

Comment: typo copy and pasting...i'll fix it. Still problem is the same.

Comment: ok learned 1.7 compiler isn't supported, not certain if leaving JRE as 1.7 will be a problem though, as it does give some convenient tools.

Comment: You can most certainly use 1.7 with android, but you can't use all of it's features, and you'll need to be careful with what libraries you use.

Comment: Just configure you IDE to Java5 source and compiled classes compatibility. As @Ewald says - Android is not Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android is not Java - so you can't use all the Java 7 features when programming for Android. This is a point of confusion for many new developers.  Your safest bet is to stick to Java 5 features, some Java 6 features work, but there are so many that simply aren't available that I tend to avoid them.

You can still use JDK 7 to build your applications, just make sure you set your IDE to only show you Java 1.5 code options.